# Microphone not working on Thinkpad X1 Yoga Gen 4

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, lenovo, thinkpad, microphone

I am running KDE Neon, and most of the system functions work great- except for the microphone. First, it didn't show up, even as a device in system settings. So, I googled it, and found that it is related to the audio for the Thinkpad X1 Carbon, so I followed some directions to install SOF drivers through this script:

https://gist.github.com/hamidzr/dd81e429dc86f4327ded7a2030e7d7d9

However, after this, while the microphone was properly detected, it only displayed static. I also followed, TO THE WORD, the instructions of some others on the Arch Linux forums. However, this didn't work properly, leading to either simply the same thing as before, or the speakers AND all audio failing to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: KDE neon is [off-topic here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) but is supported at our related site [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php/242-KDE-neon), [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), and [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/).

Comment: It's based on Ubuntu and is essentilaly ubuntu with a KDE desktop and a PPA for faster Plasma updates.

Comment: I know that. I have KDE neon on another partition. But this site's policy is to restrict Q&As to Ubuntu and its official flavors: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue as you, here is what worked for me:

**Step 1:** Install the latest kernel available from kernel.ubuntu.com

Use ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh to install the latest kernel available from kernel.ubuntu.com.

**Step 2:** Upgrade `linux-firmware` package to Ubuntu 20.04

Download and install Ubuntu 20.04’s `linux-firmware` package, which is currently at version 1.187.

**Step 3:** Blacklist `snd_hda_intel` and `snd_soc_skl`

Add the following lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist snd_hda_intel
blacklist snd_soc_skl
```

**Step 4:** Update PulseAudio config
Add the following lines to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0 channels=4
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,7 channels=4
```

**Step 5:** Reboot

Reboot and make sure you boot with the kernel installed in step 1.

Source: https://mathieularose.com/ubuntu-19-10-on-lenovo-thinkpad-x1-carbon-7th-gen/

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Now I don't have to swap to Windows for zoom calls....

Comment: Do you get audio on all 4 speakers with this method?

Comment: @stebu92 I didn't notice. Is there a way to programmatically check it?

Comment: In the sound settings when choosing the output device it will say something like "Dolby 4.1 ...". Also when clicking the "Test" button next to it, you can choose from front and rear speakers. For me (out of the box Ubuntu 20.04 on X1C7) it just says "Cannon-Point-LP HD Audio Controller". It works, but only with 2 Channels. And I am afraid of tampering with it at this point in time.

Comment: It looks like it only uses two speakers.